# Most timely source of California Fire Map data?

Tags: web-mapping, data

Fire season always has me scouring the web for satellite fire map information. Unfortunately many of the locations I find are outdated or not maintained well. What would be the best site to go to for the most timely fire data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the "Active Fire Perimeters" service on arcgis.com:  http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6940c058e2bf49b6a14a6e625df81216

You could also go directly to the source that Esri is using:  http://rmgsc.cr.usgs.gov/outgoing/GeoMAC/ I believe the [ActiveFirePerimeters.kml](http://rmgsc.cr.usgs.gov/outgoing/GeoMAC/ActiveFirePerimeters.kml) link is the one you want.

Finally, NIFC is a good provider of up to date info although I don't know of anything they provide that is readily usable by a GIS (but I haven't look too hard either):  http://www.nifc.gov/fire_info/nfn.htm

Answer (score 3):

The active fire map data from the forest service is up-to-date remote sensed data:
[Active Fire Mapping Program](http://activefiremaps.fs.fed.us/)

They have the data available in KML among other formats.

Answer (score 2):

Also check out the MODIS subsets at:
http://lance-modis.eosdis.nasa.gov/imagery/subsets/?area=na

Or you can download near-realtime hot-spots from FIRMS:

http://earthdata.nasa.gov/data/near-real-time-data/firms

Answer (score 2):

I am using the feeds from the http://www.geomac.gov/ and http://inciweb.nwcg.gov/state/5/ to get the near real time fire locations and fire perimeters.